# sms sent from java app does not appear on android device

Tags: java, android, sms

I have an application where I m using an sms provider to send sms to my android device. 
I am sending a message of the following form:

```
  message =  "value: "+Float.toString(float1)+" and ratio: "+Float.toString(float2)
```

I m using the jva.net library and the code is :

```
System.out.println("Sending sms");

InputStream response = null;
URLConnection connection = null;
try {
    connection = new URL("https://somesmsprovider.com/sms/sms.jsp?user=user&password=pass&mobiles=xxxxxxxxxx&sms="+message).openConnection();
} catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

However, what i receive on my device is just: "value:"

I guess it has to do with the encoding. The provider has an option to activate unicode encoding but that didnt help either. 
Anybody has an idea why I m not able to display the sms properly?

Thnks

Comment: can we have full code?

Comment: I'd imagine it's the spaces in the resulting URL that are causing the problem. Try replacing them with `%20` - `message = message.replace(" ", "%20");`.

Comment: Hi Mike, that s right , thanks!!! If you post your comment, as an answer I will mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the spaces in the resulting URL were causing the problem. Simply replacing them with their percent-encoded value - `%20` - seems to do the trick.

```
message = message.replace(" ", "%20");
```

If you include any characters in your message other than the alphanumerics and basic punctuation, you may need to URL-encode the whole `String`. The [`URLEncoder`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLEncoder.html) class is available in Android, though it encodes spaces as `+`, so you might have to perform a `replace()` similar to the above after the encoding, as I would imagine `+` would go through unchanged in the message body.